# Converting JSON Table Array Data in Azure Data Factory from Log Analytics REST API JSON Response to Multiple JSON Documents in same file

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm currently trying to extract data out of Log Analytics through its REST API. I have been successful at using a Copy Data activity to store the response in an Azure Data Lake Gen 2 account.

The format is roughly similar to the example from the [Log Analytics API Reference Page](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API/ResponseFormat).

```
{
"tables": [
    {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "Category",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "count_",
                "type": "long"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "Administrative",
                20839
            ],
            [
                "Recommendation",
                122
            ],
            [
                "Alert",
                64
            ],
            [
                "ServiceHealth",
                11
            ]
        ]
    }
] }
```

My dataset is much larger with more columns more values etc but the principals are the same.
What I am trying to do is generate a new JSON file that would hold the table but multiple documents in the same file e.g.

```
[{
"Category": "Administrative",
"count_": 20839
},
{
    "Category": "Recommendation",
    "count_": 122
},
{
    "Category": "Alert",
    "count_": 64
},
{
    "Category": "ServiceHealth",
    "count_": 11
}]
```

The output of this would be stored back into the data lake and then ideally could be used as a source for a copy activity to go into an Azure SQL Database.

I have tried accomplishing this using Data Flows Flattening but haven't been successful with this up until this point as when trying to map the column name it doesn't see individual column names just that level of the document where the column names are defined.

How would I go about flattening the dataset so it appears as desired? Is this an unrealistic expectation of Data flows or is this task more suitable for something like Azure Databricks?

[image: Unroll Options]

[image: Column Mapping]

Comment: You need to unroll those arrays using the Flatten transformation first.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Thanks Mark, would that be a separate flatten transformation for both columns and rows?

Comment: @johubb The rows[] can't be flatten, it's an array data not a json array. Data Factory can't work well with it even with data flow.

Comment: Each array will need its own Flatten transformation

Comment: Hi @LeonYue - Which tool would you recommend to accomplish this need if Dataflows aren’t up to the job?

Comment: @johubb Maybe you could try build function or design a stored procedure  to receive the data in copy active sink. Data Factory tools can't do that.